# How do I customize Jenkins pipeline stage view?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to customize the Jenkins pipeline stage.
In the below screenshot, I don't want the steps `Approve K8s Dev Deployment` and `Create and Deploy to k8s Dev Environment` to show in the pipeline stage view as I am skipping these based on my branch names. Below is the current output.

[image]

I want the pipeline stage view to be seen something like below without the `Approve K8s Dev Deployment` and `Create and Deploy to k8s Dev Environment`. I want my expected output as below. Am I missing out any plugins? How can I achieve this?

[image]

Below is my groovy code:

```
stages{
    stage('Checkout') {
        steps{
            checkout scm
        }
    }

    // Maven Build and Unit Tests Dev
    stage('Build and Unit Tests') {
        steps{
            build(configuration)
        }
    }

    // SonarQube Analysis
    stage('SonarQube analysis') {
        steps{
            sonarQubeGating(configuration)
        }
    }

    // Build Docker Image and Push to Artifactory
    stage('Build Docker Image and Push to Artifactory') {
        steps{
            artifactoryImagePush(configuration)
        }
    }

    // Approve DEV Deployment
    stage('Approve K8s Dev Deployment') {
        when {
            anyOf {
                expression {
                    return (env.GIT_BRANCH.startsWith('master') || env.GIT_BRANCH.startsWith('hotfix-'))
                }
            }
        }
        steps {
            approveDeployment()
        }
    }

    // Create and Deploy to Dev Environment
    stage('Create and Deploy to k8s Dev Environment') {
        when {
            anyOf {
                expression {
                    return (env.GIT_BRANCH.startsWith('master') || env.GIT_BRANCH.startsWith('hotfix-'))
                }
            }
        }
        steps {
            withCredentials([string(credentialsId: "$env.K8S_DEV_NS_TOKEN", variable: 'DEV_TOKEN')]) {
                kubernetesDeploy(hcEnv: 'dev', hcToken: "${DEV_TOKEN}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you make the stage content conditionally executed (as in your example), the stage will show up whether or not the condition is met. If you want to hide the stage when the condition is not met, the only option is to put the  stage inside the condition. The authors of the plugin caution against it though:

> Dynamic stages: in general, if you want to visualize dynamically changing stages, make it conditional to execute the stage contents, not conditional to include the stage** Stage view can handle a limited subset of cases where you're appending additional stages, but the cell-based view is not matched to changing stage structures
> (from https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-stage-view)

The downside is that in most cases, when the number of stages change, the whole stage view is reset. So every time your build changes branches, all previous builds in the stage view are gone.